# Route appears in rake routes, but not on site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm new to ruby on rails, and I'm having trouble getting up to speed.  I've set up devise for user authentication, and everything seemed to be going well.  Until I tried to get routes set up

Basically, I've deleted my /public/index.html, and I've set a new default route.  Here's my /config/routes.rb

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do
  authenticated :user do
    root :to => 'home#index'
  end
  root :to => "home#index"
  devise_for :users
end
```

Okay, so that seems simple enough.  I generated a home controller/view.  My index.html.erb is just the default.  My controller is also blank.

When I run rake routes, I can see the route to the root.

```
root       /      home#index
root       /      home#index
```

So this seems like a go!  But...It's not.  I get an error when I try and open my index

```
No route matches [GET] "/"
```

I don't feel like the details of my server should be significant, but it's nginx.  I can post my server configuration if anyone thinks it's important.

Comment: You can't set the same `root :to => "home#index"` route for both `authenticated` and non-authenticated scope. What exactly are you trying to do? If you want to display specific parts of the page to logged-in users only, try `user_signed_in?`.

Comment: It's simply a place holder.  In the future, I may (will) want to direct authenticated users to a different home page.  Your theory also didn't help.  Removing the entire conditional statement and only setting one route is giving the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Blargh.  I'm an idiot.  The server configuration I though wouldn't matter was the problem.  I had edited my nginx settings, but I left the default in Unicorn.  I never noticed before now, since the /public/index.html in both the unnecessary app and my app were the same.  Thanks for all the help though.

Answer (score 0):

You should be add resources :homes

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do
      resources :homes
      root :to => "home#index"
      devise_for :users
    end
```